# PHP Laravel: A better way than these if statements

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need to assign commissions to a newly created price. Commissions are morphable for clients, types and prices. so if there is a type commission it should get it first, fallback to clients, fallback to default.

my code works, but it feels a bit too "if-y". maybe there is a better approach to this?

```
  private function addDefaultOnlineCommission(Price $price)
   {
       $defaultCommission = (object)Commission::DEFAULT_COMMISSIONS;

       $typeCommission = $price->type->commissions()
           ->where('is_online', '=', true)->first();

       $clientCommission = $price->type->client->commissions()
           ->where('is_online', '=', true)->first();


       if (!$clientCommission && !$typeCommission) {
           $commission = $defaultCommission;
       }

       if ($clientCommission && !$typeCommission) {
           $commission = $clientCommission;
       }

       if ($typeCommission) {
           $commission = $typeCommission;
       }

       $price->commissions()->create([
           'commission_type'   => $commission->commission_type,
           'commission_value'  => $commission->commission_value,
           'min_value'         => $commission->min_value,
           'is_online'         => true,
           'valid_from'        => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
       ]);
   }
```

Comment: I'd say use elseifs, but anything beyond that might get a bit convoluted. A question like this can tend towards opinionation, but it might be better over at codereview

Comment: thanks. you are right about opinionation, but also in codereview you will get only one opinion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the functions looks to "if-y" because your statements are more complicated than they have to be. Also you are always loading all of your fallbacks, which isn't neccessary in every case. I would refactor the function to only load the next level if necessary. This could look something like this:

```
private function addDefaultOnlineCommission ( Price $price ) {

    // load the type commission
    $commission = $price->type->commissions()->where( 'is_online', '=', true )->first();

    // if there is no type commission, check client commission
    if( empty($commission) ){
        $commission = $price->type->client->commissions()->where( 'is_online', '=', true )->first();
    }

    // if there is no client commission either, fall back to the default
    if( empty($commission) ){
        $commission = (object)Commission::DEFAULT_COMMISSIONS;
    }

    $price->commissions()->create( [
        'commission_type'  => $commission->commission_type,
        'commission_value' => $commission->commission_value,
        'min_value'        => $commission->min_value,
        'is_online'        => true,
        'valid_from'       => Carbon::now()->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ),
    ] );

}
```

This does not only reduce the length of your function, it also makes it more readable imho. Additionally you avoid unnecessary queries.

*Note: You can replace empty() with is_null() as first() returns null on empty results.*

Comment: Thank you. that looks like a good approach to avoid queries also.

Answer (score 6):

Purely opinionated but I'd handle it with null coalescing operators:

```
$commission = $typeCommission ?? $clientCommission ?? $defaultCommission;
```

This will use the first non-null value.  So it sets a precedence from left to right.

Comment: You can also coalesce the actual queries to avoid making the 2nd one if the first one works.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
   if (!$clientCommission && !$typeCommission) {
       $commission = $defaultCommission;
   } else if ($clientCommission && !$typeCommission) {
       $commission = $clientCommission;
   } else {
       $commission = $typeCommission;
   }
```